# Multiple product categories non ecommerce site

Tags: ee2, matrix, categories

Hi what would be a good starting point for building the following functionality with EE:

Level 1: Main product categories - page listing all main categories

Level 2: Selecting a main category takes user to list of sub categories within the main category

Level 3: Selecting subcategory takes user to a list of products within the subcategory.

Level 4: Product page

Importantly products would need to feature in several categories which would be easily selected in the admin panel by my client.

Would an addon like Matrix help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see one single reason for an add-on other than [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) on this.

The [default category management](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/category_management.html) of EECMS can handle this pretty well.